# measured variables with almost zero variance

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am interested in knowing some examples for measured variables, which show almost zero variance.
Could anyone list me some examples?
I am not sure, but perhaps the measured variable "speed" of a photon should have almost zero variance?

Answer (score 0):

Removing noise from measurement itself:

-Earth's gravity
-Light speed

Perhaps all Physical Constants?

Comment: Earth's gravity varies significantly, for example from about $9.776 m/s^2$ in Mexico City to $9.826 m/s^2$ in Anchorage, affected by latitude, altitude and local physical geodesy.

Comment: @Henry.  You are right.  I should have written Newtonian Constant of Gravitation instead.  Standard gravity is not a measurement but an agreement.  The actual Earth's gravity will indeed vary.